# Append text inputs based on value provided by the user w/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inputsNum" />
<div id="content"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#inputsNum").bind('change paste keyup', function () {
    var count = $(this).val(),
        content = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
       content += $(this).append($('<input>').prop('type', 'text'));
    }
    $(this).next().html(content);  
});
```

Hi,

want to let the user to add multiple text inputs based on value he provided

i wrote the above code but i'm getting [object Object] error repeated actually based on the value i provided  , means its working but why its doesn't append the text inputs !

need your help

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0x46kta3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputsNum").bind('change paste keyup', function () {
        var count = $(this).val(),
            content = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
           content += '<input type="text" />';
        }
        $('#content').html(content);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing `content += $(this).append($('<input>').prop('type', 'text'))` with `content += "<input type='text' />";`

The `append` function that you are using returns an object and not the HTML as string like you expect it to. Thus when you add it as a string, the toString() method of the object converts it to [object Object] and that gets appended to your HTML